# Error '1004' Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba, range, sumifs

I am trying to assign a range to my variable Arg1.

```
dim wkb2 as workbook
set wkb2 =  workbooks("File2.xlsx")
dim ws2 as worksheet
set ws2 = wkb2.worksheets(k)

Dim Arg1 As Range 'the range to sum
Dim Arg2 As Range 'criteria1 range`enter code here`
Dim Arg3 As Variant 'criteria1
Dim Arg4 As Range 'criteria2 range
Dim Arg5 As Variant 'criteria2

Set Arg1 = ws2.Range(Cells(i + 2, 6), Cells(i + 2, 6).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 
0))
Set Arg2 = ws2.Range(Cells(i + 2, 4), Cells(i + 2, 4).End(xlDown))
Set Arg4 = ws2.Range(Cells(i + 2, 5), Cells(i + 2, 5).End(xlDown))
Arg3 = ws1.Cells(j, 20)
Arg5 = ws1.Cells(j, 21)

ws1.Cells(j, 23).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Arg1, Arg2, 
Arg3, Arg4, Arg5)
```

I get the error (in title) when i Set Arg1 = ...

What I am trying to do is to assign to Arg1 a range from Cells(i+2, 6):Cells(i+2, "1 cell higher after using Ctrl Down"). So for example if i+2 = 5, I would want Range.("F5:F9"), assuming last row is Row10.

Any help is greatly appreciated! (:

Comment: Is `ws2`properly set? Where is its value assigned?

Comment: ws1 is not declare or assigned. Also Dim k As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
are missing

Comment: What's the value of `k` ? Is it > 0 and does its number correspond to the correct worksheet? Is `File2.xlsx`opened? Inspect the value of `wkb2.Worksheets(k)` to check whether you have the correct worksheet at all.

Answer (score 0):

The following should compile if you adjust the reference to ws1 to the sheet you are using

Also, placed variables together.

```
   Sub test()

    Dim wkb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Arg1 As Range       'the range to sum
    Dim Arg2 As Range       'criteria1 range`enter code here`
    Dim Arg3 As Variant     'criteria1
    Dim Arg4 As Range       'criteria2 range
    Dim Arg5 As Variant     'criteria2
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long 'Or if it is a worksheet name then as string
    Dim j As Long
    Set wkb2 = Workbooks("File2.xlsx")

    'k =   ''Set K variable here

    Set ws2 = wkb2.Worksheets(k)
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  ' Change as appropriate
    Set Arg1 = ws2.Range(Cells(i + 2, 6), Cells(i + 2, 6).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0))
    Set Arg2 = ws2.Range(Cells(i + 2, 4), Cells(i + 2, 4).End(xlDown))
    Set Arg4 = ws2.Range(Cells(i + 2, 5), Cells(i + 2, 5).End(xlDown))

    Arg3 = ws1.Cells(j, 20)
    Arg5 = ws1.Cells(j, 21)

    ws1.Cells(j, 23).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4, Arg5)

End Sub
```

Comment: You `Dim` k but you don't initialize it. Without setting a value to k, `Worksheets(k)` will fail.

Comment: They haven't given a value but yes i should initialize for each. My bad!